# Firebase Real-Time database vs Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Im using Real-Time database to storage my users Profiles.

Each of the profiles can contain multiple rooms, where each of them contain their own picture creating a quite complex structure.

Here an example: [image]

To make it easier to store the pictures to the corresponding profile, and room I am changing my pictures Bitmap in android to a String before I parse the object into the Database, and then when I get the object back I transform the String back to the Bitmap.

I was just wondering if this comes with any down cost in the future. Or if this implementation is safe where we put more data in the databases.

Comment: This is verging on asking for opinion-based answers.

Comment: That is a weird way of storing the pictures into the database. This will also increase the overhead as first, the image has to be converted into the bitmap.  I would suggest to go with the storage option and store the URL of images into your database.

Answer (score 5):

With your current database structure as-is, you will run into problems.

With the Realtime Database and this structure, everytime you request "user/SOME_ID", you will download all of the data below it - including your serialized images. Consult the [database structure guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data) for information on how to flatten your data out so this doesn't occur.

Furthermore, I would recommend making use of [Cloud Storage for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/start) to store your images in their native binary format rather than serializing to Base64 taking up ~30% more space. Like the RTDB, storage can be secured with rules if you store the files in structured locations like "user/SOME_ID/roomImages/ROOM_ID/..." or "roomImages/ROOM_ID/..."

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not safe and bad implementation because u save users data in a third party service even without any encryption rather than storing it in your back-end which you have full control on it. 
if I was A user for your app I didn't like that but if this app just for testing something there is no problem.

Comment: Well its for a university project, we are supposed to develop a android application (where we do not have to take any security in consideration so far...) I was more worried about performance than security when asking this. Also does the firebase storage bring encryption to the files compared to firebase real-time databases?

Comment: [#AskFirebase](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TSzhzR4wzSE) published a video on GDPR and Privacy topics including many useful links to their policies. The [RTDB vs. Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore) suggests that Firestore will be easier to use when it comes to geo-fencing your stored data. There's also an extensive talk on [Serverless GDPR compliance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhgWEXkbn4A). Lastly, [Riya Sinha](https://hackernoon.com/@riyavsinha) has an article on using [client-side encryption with Firebase](https://hackernoon.com/60dd55abadb2).